Resources on Advanced Topics in Standard Model: nonperturbative phenomena, phase transitions, etc
I'm interested in some books on Standard Model physics that discuss advanced topics in quantum field theory. By this I mean topics such as instantons, sphalerons, and friends, the electroweak phase transition (QCD phase transition would be nice as well), maybe anomalies, and possibly other such advanced topics. Most books I know (such as Schwartz, Peskin & Schroeder, Weinberg, etc) will usually only mention these sorts of topics briefly at the end, but not discuss it in much depth.
As one might guess, right now I'm interested in applications to cosmology. QFT/Particle Physics at the level of Schwartz, Peskin & Schroeder, Weinberg, etc is an acceptable pre-requisite, and so is general relativity (if this is relevant).
In case a book is not possible, lecture notes, review articles and etc are surely acceptable as well.

A classic. The side issues are parsed out in review articles, not books.
